# VS Code keeps making copies of my Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a new installation of VS Code 1.62.3
When I open .ipynb files that were created in Jupyter Notebook and run the first piece of code, it keeps creating a second copy of the file with a hexidecimal name as a postfix.
Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

This doesn't happen when I create the file in VS Code, only those created in Jupyter Lab.
Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can stop this?
Thank you